# copy memory content from intptr

Tags: c#

Aloha-everyone,
I would like to to know how to convert a memory content of an intptr into its equivalent data.
I should be missing the meaning of IntPtr that I think it is a pointer to somewhere in memory, for example a string, I would like to get that string. Is there a method to do that ? Thank you

Comment: **1.** _"convert a memory content into its equivalent data"_ does not make any sense. Memory contents can be interpreted in an infinite number of ways -- you need to know *what* it represents (i.e. you need to know its data type). **2.** An `IntPtr` is just a native-size integer (unlike e.g. `Int32`, which is always 32 bits wide). As such in interop scenarios it's often used in places where memory addresses (pointers) are passed around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the [`System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.aspx) class (hyperlink to MSDN).

There's a [`Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.aspx) method that accepts an `IntPtr` source and copies characters into a `char[]` array. It should be easy to convert that into a regular `string`. There's also other methods that interpret the memory content differently; that is, you need to know what *type* of data you're expecting at the memory location you're looking at, and then you need to choose the appropriate overload of `Copy`.

That being said, an `IntPtr` is really just a native-size integer (unlike e.g. Int32, which is always 32 bits wide). As such, it's often used in interop scenarios in places where memory addresses (pointers) are passed around… thus you find the above method in the `System.Runtime.InteropServices` namespace.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, you can use [Marshal.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146631.aspx) for that, e.g.

```
IntPtr pointer = ...;
byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
Marshal.Copy(pointer, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Which retrieves 100 bytes from the specified memory address to a managed byte array.

“A string” is a very complicated concept – *what kind* of string? Do you know its length beforehand? Is it zero-terminated? Do you know its encoding? Etc.

Answer (score 1):

[Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b620dhe.aspx) and [Marshal.PtrToStringUni](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostringuni.aspx) are what you are looking for. The Marshall class contains lots of other methods for performing similar native/managed marshalling tasks.